# Monitor power saving not activating in 20.04

Tags: graphics, power-management, intel-graphics, monitor

The screen starts to dim but then when it's all black the backlight doesn't turn off and the cursor is still showing.

Could this have something to do with the "no suitable video mode found" (relating to hwmode in grub) error I used to get at boot? I googled workarounds and now it's gone but the issue I'm having might be ralated.

I'm on a Intel iGPU (i5-6500T).

Comment: *I googled workarounds* and have you applied any? If so please [edit] the question and describe what you did exactly and thoroughly.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really recall what I did but I think the issue (both monitor not turning off for power saving and the video error have to do with me using a 4k screen. There's no issue when switching to a 1080p screen.